# Laravel Model update error : Cannot unbind $this of closure using $this

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, php-8

My code was working properly before, But recently it shows this error in some parts of the website. `Cannot unbind $this of closure using $this`. When I checked the stack trace it's showing inside Laravel Framework.

[image: Laravel Error]

This is my code from where the Error is Occurring.

```
class SubscriptionService
{
    public static function upgradeToLeader(Member|Authenticatable $member, Package $package, string $preferredMeetingType = null)
    {
        $member->syncRoles($package->role);

        /*** Error is showing in the following Line ***/
        $member->update(['preferred_meeting_type' => $preferredMeetingType ?? null]);

        event(new Upgraded($member, $package));
    }
}
```

[image: Error in SubscriptionService.php]

Comment: Can you click on the SubscriptionService in your trace there, and show what it says there?

Comment: @aynber I've added the stack trace